# Hashrate is extremely unstable. Why?

Tags: hashrate

Good Evening

I currently mine with my R9 280x and I'm gaining around 13 Mhs on average which is not bad.

[image]

Why is my hashrate so unstable? My card runs at less than 60 degrees and it's overclocked to 1.2 Ghz core and 1.6 Ghz mem...

Thanks for answering!

Comment: What about when you see something like this ? Can someone explain me the possible reason ? It was very stable and high in the 24h before this period. Thanks in advance ![Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfVqP.jpg)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19103)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variance in your effective hashrate is caused by the pool calculating your rate based on the number of shares you submit in a given period.

If you're lucky you'll submit an above average number of shares and the pool will show your effective rate as being higher than usual. Conversely, if you're unlucky and submit fewer shares in a period then your effective hashrate will drop below the hashrate that you're actually mining at. Over short periods of time this effect can result in some quite large variations.

If you look at your average hashrate over a 24 hour period (assuming you mine constantly during that time) then it should be close to your actual rate.

Comment: Great. Thank you for your answer. What do you mean with "submit lots of shares"?

Comment: Just an above average number due to your luck. I've edited the post to clarify this point.